# I am using if/else statements to calculate salary and am receiving this error: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean, typeerror, branch

I am trying to calculate bi-weekly salary, calculating the tax rate as salary increases. When I use if/else statements to change the tax rate on different salaries, it gives me an error.

```
salary = (input('Enter salary: '))
marital_status = input('Enter marital status M for married or S for other: ')

if marital_status is 'S':
    if salary <= 10000.00:
        print(salary * .05)
    else salary <= 50000.00:
        print(500.00 + (salary * .105)
    else salary > 50000.00
        print(4700.00 + (salary * .2025)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string you are accepting via input by using the ‘float(string)’ function.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the remark from Roger, there are some unclosed parenthesis in your code.
Also maybe you should use elif instead of else as your else statement test conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use elif in place of else if ı believe.I don't know why but the problem causes by your floats in your loops, and as mentioned before, you have unclosed parenthesis on your code. Cant explain the solution but here is the working code.

```
salary = float(input("Enter salary: "))
marital_status = input("Enter marital status M for married or S for other: ")

if marital_stat == "S":
    if salary <= 10000:
        print(salary * 0.05)
    elif salary <= 50000:
        print(salary * 0.105)
    elif salary > 50000:
        print(4700 + (salary*0.2025))
```